# Ant mapper returns escaped paths

Tags: java, ant

This is not truly a YUI-related question.

I am trying to use YUI Compressor(in fact a .jar application) for multiple JS files. I would like to get those files automatically(as opposed to specifying every file's name in build.xml).

Here is my build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="CUIProject" default="prod">

<target name="-load.properties">
<loadproperties>
  <file file="minify.properties"/>
</loadproperties>
</target>

<!--Minify JS files-->
<target name="-js.minify">
<apply executable="java" parallel="false" dest="${build.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}"/>
    <mapper>
        <globmapper from="*.js" to="*-min.js" handledirsep="yes"/>
    </mapper>
    <arg value="-jar"/>
    <arg path="${minifier.dir}"/>
    <srcfile/>
    <arg value="-o"/>
    <targetfile/>
</apply>
</target>


<!--Build-->
<target name="prod"
depends="
-load.properties,
-js.minify
">
</target>
</project>
```

The problem is that I get a FileNotFound exception because for some reason the `<targetdir/>` is somehow escaped: the `\` separator from Windows is used as an escaping character, so my path because just one very large word.

How can I avoid such a behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with YUI. The easiest way I found is to use the [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) `<for>` task.

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${antlib.dir}/antcontrib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<!-- Minimize Concatinated JavaScript Files -->
<for param="concat.dir">
    <dirset dir="${work.js.dir}">
        <include name="*"/>
    </dirset>
    <sequential>
        <echo message="[java] Minimized @{concat.dir}/concat-${build.id}-min.js>"/>
        <java jar="${yui.compressor.jar}"
            failonerror="true"
            fork="true">
            <arg value="-o"/>
            <arg value="@{concat.dir}/concat-${build.id}-min.js"/>
            <arg value="@{concat.dir}/concat-${build.id}.js"/>
        </java>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Also take a look at the [`<pathconvert>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task. This will convert the path separator from one OS to another. This may fix your issue. The [File Mapper page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) in Ant's manual contains some examples using `<pathconvert>`.

Comment: I have tried various things by now and I suspect that the YUI compressor does not automatically create the destination folders. Can this be the cause?

Comment: @Dragos  Could very well be, and it's easy enough to fix. Just add in a `<mkdir>` task before the `<java>` task. Here I just happen to be using the same directory, but I can understand if you're using a different one. I can say that what I have here works because it's pretty much cut and pasted from my program.